# What does the number mean in the specification for a mincer?

Tags: equipment

I'm looking at buying a mincer and am seeing them listed with descriptions like:

- Cast Iron Meat Mincer # 12
- Kitchen Craft Cast Iron Mincer 5

I haven't yet seen any mention of what the number means though! Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number specifies the diameter of the grinder plate

- #5 is 2 1/8 inches
- #8 is 2 1/2 inches
- #10 and #12  are 2 3/4 inches
- #20 and #22 are  3 1/4 inches
- #32 is 3 7/8 inches